# Is integer comparison in Python constant time?

Tags: python, cryptography

is integer comparison in Python constant time? Can I use it to compare a user-provided `int` token with a server-stored `int` for crypto in the way I would compare strings with `constant_time_compare` from `django.utils.crypto`, i.e. without suffering timing attacks?

Alternatively, is it more secure to convert to a string and then use the above function?

Comment: Is your question: Is ``1 == 4`` O(1)? (What does this have to do with Django?)

Comment: My question is 1==4 constant time in the true meaning of the phrase (I think technically it can be O(1) but take predictable variations of time for different inputs). And re: Django - I wrote a longer question in terms of the constant_time_compare function defined in django.utils.crypto but I trimmed it for brevity and forgot to remove the Django label. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes **for a given size of integer** - by default python integers that get big become `long` and then have potentially infinite length - the  compare time then grows with the size. If you restrict the size of the integer to a `ctypes.c_uint64` or `ctypes.c_uint32` this will not be the case.

Note that compare with 0 is a special case, normally much faster, due to the hardware actions *many CPUs have a special flag for 0*, but if you are using/allowing seeds or tokens with a values of 0 you are asking for trouble.

Comment: This isn't my domain, so I might be off-base here, but it seems like the idea behind a timing attack is to exploit the fact that checking the equality of two bitstrings usually "short circuits": If I have two bitstrings which differ in their first bit, the comparison returns faster than if they are the same up to 10,000 bits, but differ on the 10,001st. So is it actually true that python integer comparison (for a given number of bits) takes the same time, regardless of whether the integers differ in their first bit or only in their last? That seems like a surprising implementation!

Comment: @jme Down at the hardware layer things are normally done processor word width so the fastest and most common implementation for == is load both words, XOR and check for 0 making a total of 4 op codes for a word compare - as I said above most processors have a hardware flag that is set if the register contains 0. So it will be constant time as long as you are less than a word width which an integer is but a python long can be infinite length compare on that works as you suggest but not bit wise rather it is word wise. A compare of a long will always take the max time for the length to match.

Comment: In which case I'm presuming people don't more often use ints for HMACs and tokens is that you most likely want more than 64 bits of entropy to play with... In my case my tokens are 64 bit ints so I will use regular int comparison and not worry about timing attacks. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveBarnes Ah, that makes sense. Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Compare time certainly grows with size, but it's not guaranteed to be constant time for a given size. What if you're using 32-bit python with 64-bit numbers? Just use known constant time functions and don't try to micro-optimise in a risky way.

Comment: @owencm please note that 64 bit ints are only words on 64 bit systems with 64 bit python but on 32 bit systems 64 bit ints or even 32 bit ints that are over sys.maxint, (2147483647), will be longs due to the sign so will no longer be sign constant.